# Efficient way of hiding elements with certain classes $.each, for, etc

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array populated with classes. I need to loop across this array and hide any elements with that particular class.

```
// Array of classes
// hide.length ~ 100
```

This is my current implemntation:

```
// Hide all elements with these class names
$.each(hide, function(key, filter_class){
  $('li.'+filter_class, '.result_row_items').hide();
});
```

I believe this would be a more efficient (performance wise) way:

```
for(i=0;i<hide.length;i++){
  $('li.'+hide[i], '.result_row_items').hide();
}
```

Would this be even better?

```
// Create string of class names
var classes = '';
for(i=0;i<hide.length;i++){
  classes += 'li.'+ hide[i] + ', '
}
// Remove trailing comma and space
classes = classes.substring(0, classes.length - 2);
$(classes, '.result_row_items').hide();
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by efficient? Are you talking about performance or number of lines?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like that?

```
$("li." + hide.join(",li."), ".result_row_items").hide();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/B9fXP/

Comment: This seems like a good way to joint the classes into a string. However what i'm really trying to get to the bottom of is - is it more efficient to give jquery a bunch of classes in a string OR loop across the classes and get jquery to implement each class hide on its own?

Comment: @JulianS Well, that's tough question IMO. It's even hard to find the answer in the [jQuery sources](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js). Bunch of classes in a string will anyway be split into array of objects by jQuery constructor. On the first side, it will be done with a regular expression, which may slow the process. On the other side, running jQuery constructor for every single class selector may also decrease the performance. I must agree with Christoph, jsperf.com should help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
$(hide).filter('.class').hide();
```

or

```
for (var i = 0; class = classes[i++];) {
    $('li.'+ class).hide();
}
```